# need an event triggered if the page has scrolled 200px down (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I want to show and hide a piece of code if i scroll and the page is for example half way, i have tried to use window scroll but this doesnt works(no errors, clean code, different browsers, different jQuery versions), but this doesn't trigger anything, so i am looking for a better way to show and hide a div if i scrolldown.

used this to trigger an event(not working)

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    alert('works')
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using the window.onload function (that's how they use it in jQuery examples):

```
window.onload = (function(){
  $(window).scroll(function () { 
    if( $(window).scrollTop() > 200 ) {
      // Display something
    }
  })
})
```

Comment: This works but i have found the problem, i cant give the html selector an height:100% value....

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish with height 100%? If you want the code to display at half the page, you need to calculate half the page in pixels like: `$(document).height() / 2;`

Comment: i have fixed it, i had a couple of wrong values in the code. Thanks for the solution!!